# Electron auto updater error when running in dev mode

Tags: node.js, electron, auto-update

When I run an Electron app with auto-updating integrated, in dev mode. I get this error:

```
Error: Could not get code signature for running application
```

I have read a little about it, and from what I understand, apple auto-updating Electron applications must have a code signature on the app.

My question is: Shouldn't I be able to run my application in dev mode, without the code signature?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test the auto-updater code when you are in the development environment. You need to generate builds of your application say 1.0.0 and 1.0.1

When you run the setup of build 1.0.0 on your local machine then the code will look for updates available or no. In our case 1.0.1 is available. So it updates the 1.0.0 application by 1.0.1

This is true only for Windows OS